# Data validation in Excel based on value matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation, dropdownlist

I'm really struggeling to solve the following task. I have a data matrix where vehicles and features are matched.

[image]

Now I want to use this as source for Excels input validation feature in a second table.

[image]

I know that this should be solved with the data(input) validation feature.

But how to configure the following: "Show only those features in dropdown list, which are marked "x" for the choosen Asset in column A"?

Comment: You mean to say when Bike is selected as asset then only Small & Light should be listed in Drop down, did you ever try Dependant Drop Down ?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, yes, this is what I mean. What do you mean by dependent drop-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Netblognet,, I would like suggest a method called Dependent Drop Down list to solve the issue.

First about Dependent Drop Down.

It's as simple as cascading list of items (should any Country, City, Product and others) that display choices depending on the value selected in First Drop down.

Check the Screen Shot below.

[image]

**How it works:**

*Part ONE:*

- Create list of Vehicles along with their categories in Range **J48:L51**.
- Place Cell pointer to Cell **N48.**
- Hit `Data TAB` & click on `Data Validation`.
- Select `List` as `Validation Criteria` from **Setting TAB.**
- And for `Source` select `J48:L48` will looks like `$J$48:$L$48`.
- Finish with `OK`.

*Part TWO:*

- Select Data Range `J48:L51`.
- Go to `Formulas`, `Defined Names` then `Create from Selection`.
- Or you may use shortcut **Control + Shift + F3** also.
- From the `Create Names From Selection` dialog, only check the `Top row` option and finish with `OK`.
- Select Cell `P48`.
- Again go to `Data Validation` & for `Source` field, enter the formula **=INDIRECT(N48)**. Where  `N48` is the cell contains First Drop Down, finally click OK.
- Now, whenever you select Vehicle Name in First Drop Down, related categories will listed in 2nd Drop Down List automatically.

**N.B.**

- Whenever you update list in `J48:L51`, you need to modify the Data Range using `Formula Tab` then `Name Manger`.

*- Adjust the Data Range as needed.*

Comment: @Netblognet happy to help you ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Just for completeness: I did a combination of your answer and VBA scripting. I wrote a script which resolves my matrix table (the one with the x's) to plain lists, which I then used for input validation like shown in your example. Thus I can keep the simplicity in editing (matrix table), while using the validation list feature at the same time.

Comment: @netblognet,, it's really wonderful idea. If you feel you can post that combination as an Answer to contribute the community. ☺